# First Website - Security Concerns

Tags: html, wordpress, security, web

I have taught myself HTML/CSS and some JavaScript as a hobby, and have reached the point where I am comfortable building a clean simple website. The company I work for (we do nothing related to coding) has a website that is quite outdated so naturally I saw this as an opportunity for my first live site. I approached my Managers at work to take a look at my first mock up and they loved it and want me to revamp our current site.

The one concern they have with me being a rookie is the issue of web security.  Essentially they want to make sure that the website I build leaves no vulnerability for someone to hack through our server, start editing our website, etc.

There are no interactive components to the current website.  I plan to build this website with only HTML and CSS, and perhaps add some JavaScript later down the road once I progress in my learning a bit more.  There are no account logins or areas to enter personal information anywhere on the site.

My question comes down to this -- what can I do to ensure that the website I build is not leaving our company vulnerable? I have done a lot of searching around Stack Overflow and other websites but I am not confident I am finding the correct information.

Details that might make a difference:

- Our company website is hosted through godaddy.com
- Our website is currently on Wordpress, but I will probably not use Wordpress for the new website

I greatly appreciate all of your help!

Comment: become familiar with the OWASP Top 10 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013 . The easy answer is use modsecurity

Answer (score 2):

since there should be no direct interacting with the server ex PHP and AJAX only HTML CSS and js there should be no security issue, as js and HTML can't edit/delete/read server files, only server-side programming can. eventually you may want to invest in PHP almost no website is complete without PHP or AJAX. take me for example, I used to use just HTML, CSS, and js. then I wanted to do more.. log form answers to a file, show different pages based on the query string. these things are virtually impossible in a HTML, CSS, and js only environment. I would also recommend atleast getting free protection from cloud flare.. they give free shared hosting wildcard SSL, and free DDOS protection, granted for a business you might want to invest a little more than free but free would be a good starting point

also you could pay someone to test the vulnerability of your company, take for example OurMine. a legal hacking group.. you pay them to test your security and they do just that. (they claim they don't log anything that they get) otherwise there might be vulnerabilities you may not be aware of

Answer (score 0):

When you are concerning about just AJAX call, I would help you out for following suggestion regarding "Function access rule from AJAX".

By adding "_" as a prefix for Function name, we can prevent function to be called from The Web publicly. This is the best practice when we need some specific function to be accessed via AJAX only.

Kindly, refer my answer given in other question.
[[Website Security: How to learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197596/website-security-how-to-learn/39788967#39788967][1])